# Kafka ACLs: Add user to multiple topics in one command

Tags: apache-kafka, acl

I have a Kafka server running in ACLs. I can add User:Bob to topic test

```
bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:Bob --operation Read --topic test
```

but I want to add User:bob to topic1, topic2 and topic3.

Is there a way to add a user to multiple topics ACLs in one command? it is just to reduce the setup time (performance).

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can give 2 `--topic` arguments such as:

```
bin/kafka-acls.sh --add --allow-principal User:Bob --operation Read --topic test --topic test2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a small script:

### `kafka-custom-acls.sh`

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

for i in $@;
do
    bin/kafka-acls.sh --authorizer kafka.security.auth.SimpleAclAuthorizer --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181 --add --allow-principal User:Bob --operation Read --topic $i
done
```

Invoke the script as follows

```
./kafka-custom-acls.sh topic1 topic2 topic3
```

Comment: This works but I was wondering if there was a faster way to add multiple users to a topic